# PHP Composer ci require

Tags: php, composer-php

Using composer i would like to have a custom require section for using with ci server.

Something like this:

```
{
    "require": {
       ...
    },
    "require-dev": {
       ...
    },
    "require-ci": {
       ...
    },
}
```

Is this possible? In composer documentation i can only find references to using require and require-dev

Answer (score 0):

Composer only has the two kinds of dependencies: Stuff needed to run your software, and stuff needed to develop it.

Unless you implement another category inside Composer, you'd have to live with what you get.

What kind of software should that require-ci category contain? If it is software to run tests in CI, use require-dev (even if your local developers don't need it). Or make these components be part of the ready-made CI server you use. If you think about Travis CI, the script that is configuring the VM should install anything that is not part of your software, so if you though about running `composer install --ci` to grab all things that are needed on Travis CI, you'd probably use a different approach like `composer create-project that/ci-tool` in your script.

Comment: Its kind of the other way around.  I have some tools used for developing that take a while to install and they are not required during the build on ci (travis)

Comment: Feature requests should go to the projects website at Github: https://github.com/composer/composer then.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good pattern as you are effectively sandboxing your CI's configuration and that breaks the whole point of continuous integration.

The workspace and testing surface on your CI jobs should match the production environment as closely as possible if the integration and acceptance testing results are to be reliable.